# UIStackView dynamic height image

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, uistackview

I'm following tutorial in appcoda. The problem is when preview the stackview between different devices the height not following the size of the device.

Here is what i want:

[image: Here is what i want]

and here is what i got:

[image: here is what i got]

Do constraint effect height in different devices ? or you need code the height for different devices ?

Comment: try setting content mode of your image view to aspect fill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose the Image in storyboard and try to change "Content Mode" option as shown in this picture below

[image: picture.]

I believe "Aspect Fill" will fix it.

Comment: now the image become smaller in big screen https://imgur.com/a/K6CL7
do i set the content mode first before embed the stackview ?

Comment: No it doesn't matter when you do it. Whenever you do it, it will take effect. But as I see in the picture you sent in the comment, the picture size is too small. What I suggest is to set the constraints of your image from the right and left edge of the screen, so that in any screen size, your image has a constant space from the right and left edge of the super view of it. (in your case the super view of the image is the hole screen of the device)

Comment: update its seem i make a mistake now the picture its like should be thx @TeddyBear but now the image and text position is ruined https://imgur.com/a/63CzG. How to make the image below the text ?

Comment: You can use vertical stackview. If you put both, the text and the picture, in the stackview, and add a constraint for the picture to set its distance with the object above it (or either adding a constraint for the text to set a distance with the object under it), Xcode will automatically handles the problem, no matter what device it is.

Comment: do i set the constraint for every image to object above it ?

Comment: Depends on the situation but in your case, yes.